# MySQL Finding Partial Duplicates

Tags: mysql, database

I've got the following table, and I'm trying experiment with it. Here is the table:

> Mobiles:
>   - id: '1', productname: 'Apple'
>   - id: '2', productname: 'Apple'
>   - id: '3', productname: 'Samsung'
>   - id: '4', productname: 'Alcatel phone'
>   - id: '5', productname: 'Alcatel'
>   - id: '6', productname: 'Blackberry'

I'm am currently using this MySQL query to not display the duplicates:

> SELECT DISTINCT productname FROM `mobiles`

And the result displays:

> - Apple
> - Samsung
> - Alcatel Phone
> - Alcatel
> - Blackberry

Now my question is if their is anything I can add to my mysql to search the database to check the the first word is not a duplicate or something along those lines? Or if more than 8 characters are the same regard it as a duplicate? So that I can get my data to display as follows:

> - Apple
> - Samsung
> - Alcatel
> - Blackberry

I hope Someone out there would be able to help me out with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to the rescue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(productname,' ',1) FROM mobiles
```